# Sign in with google without using identity in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

How could I make sign in with Google and Facebook without using Identity and without using a cookie?

I'm using JWT authentication and build all of my API manually and I use Entity Framework to build my database. I hope to find an answer

Comment: `AddGoogle` middleware is not actually for a JWT authentication flow, Here is a discussing in this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21719), you can refer to it.